# Xamarin forms Linker in IOS problems

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, linker

When I compile my project in ah hoc or release using the linker for assemblys only,  my app doesn't work properly when installing the .ipa file in the iphone, the app cant even connect to the server to validate the login.

How can i fix  this?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What error are you getting?

Comment: This is the error:
http://prntscr.com/kz0dlt

Answer (score 0):

What always seems to work for me iOS-wise is the following: **(note that this is in visual studio, since I don't know what you're working with)**

[image: settings]

I put the option in the toolbar as *Ad-hoc*, and in the bundle signing as *Release* and do a **clean + rebuild** afterwards.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I using Visual Studio too, doesnt work is the same, Thanks anyway.